# JNLP: Cannot pass arguments to main

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I wrote a program which simply output args[0]. If no args is passed to the main, then it will output "Hello World"

```
class test {
public test(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        args = new String[] { "Hello World" };
    }
    new test(args[0]);
}}
```

In the .jnlp file, the corresponding part is written as:

```
<application-desc main-class="test"/>
  <argument>TEST1</argument>
</application-desc>
```

However, after running this jnlp, it outputs "Hello World"

Can anyone please help me figure out what's the reason?

Comment: solved it when deleting the "/" in <application-desc main-class="test"/>

Comment: In future, you might validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It checks things like that, and a lot more besides.

Comment: @OneFingerCoder There's a badge for answering your own question _well_. It's _encouraged_ behavior here.

Comment: Thank you all, Andrew and Donal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the `/` in `<application-desc main-class="test"/>`